# how to display message in page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to display a success message in page in mvc?

for example when user submit a page then after processing the data, I need to display a message telling that the data successfully submitted.

Comment: Popup is not enough ?

Comment: Follow this guideline: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use viewbag to pass your message from controller to view like below:-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Name = "data successfully submitted.";
    return View();
}
```

In View:

```
@ViewBag.Name 
@ViewData["Name"]
```